# Are "Dynafit"/tech ski boots compatible with frame-style touring bindings?

Tags: skiing, alpine-touring, ski-bindings

I'm new to alpine touring skiing, and I'd like to purchase some new (more comfortable) AT boots. I currently have frame-style bindings on my AT skis. I'd like an "upgrade path". Can I purchase and use tech-style boots in my current ski bindings and then (one day) buy new tech bindings and use the same boots?

Or, will I have to get new tech bindings at the same time I purchase new tech-style ("Dynafit") touring boots?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is tech binding compatible boots will work fine with non-tech AT bindings in the vast majority of circumstances.

The more involved answer is (as always for safety gear) to check the specific manufacturer recommendations for a specific boot/binding combination. [Here is a quote](https://www.evo.com/guides/how-to-buy-alpine-touring-ski-boots) to support that:

> MOST AT boots and alpine boots will work with MOST frame AT bindings (Marker, Salomon/Atomic, Tyrolia, Fritschi), but be sure to check the manufacturer’s recommendations. Boots with minimalist soles like the Dynafit TLT5, TLT6 and TLT7, Atomic Backland series, La Sportiva Stratos/Syborg, Arc'teryx Procline and Scarpa Alien series boots are compatible only with tech bindings.

---

While most alpine boots will work with most frame AT bindings **don't use your AT boots in your alpine bindings**. The rubber on the sole of the AT boot may cause your alpine binding to release at a higher and/or inconsistent DIN value.

Comment: Not only do AT soles influence normed release, they often don't fit at all into standard alpine bindings due to height issues - many (all?) AT frame bindings can be adjusted in height of the front piece.